# Apache Tomcat 8.5 : SSL ENABLED IN IE BUT NOT IN CHROME

Tags: ssl, java-8, tls1.2, server.xml, tomcat8.5

I have enabled SSL for a site using jdk 1.8 and Tomcat 8.5.23.

When I hit the site in IE, first time it shows:

"Can't connect securely to this page 
This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening,try contacting website's owner."

When I hit the site second time, the page loads and the application functionality works fine with SSL enabled.

When I hit the site in chrome no matter how many times, it shows:

"This site can't provide a secure connection

Abcd.xyz.com didn't accept your login certificate, or one may not have been provided.

Try contacting the system admin.

ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT"

In server.xml I have added below in the connector tag:

SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"

I also could not find any error in the log files.
Please help me. :([image]

Comment: Add clientAuth="false" to your connector.

Comment: I am using APR connector on port 443. And the tag doesn't contain clientAuth parameter.

Comment: The SSLVerifyClient="optional" is causing tomcat to prompt the browser for a certificate.  If you are not trying to do certificate based authentication set it to none or remove it since the default is none.

Comment: I am doing a certificate based authentication and want them to be recognized.